# Why are <none> images created and why doesn't Docker clean them up?

Tags: docker

I know how to removed containers and images.

What I don't understand is why those `<none>` images are created in the process of a `docker build -t my_container .` or a similar command.

Running `docker images` will give me something like that:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED              VIRTUAL SIZE
go_dev              latest              f6ed22ea5c46        About a minute ago   624.7 MB
<none>              <none>              1c99b48b31fb        About a minute ago   624.7 MB
<none>              <none>              0f9be2c252f9        8 minutes ago        624.7 MB
ubuntu              trusty              b7cf8f0d9e82        8 weeks ago          188.3 MB
ubuntu              latest              b7cf8f0d9e82        8 weeks ago          188.3 MB
```

Also, I think there must be a good reason why those `<none>` images stay around and are not cleaned up automatically.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/reference/commandline/cli.md#untagged-images

Comment: @BMW This link answers why untagged images are created in the `docker build` process. But would you know why _docker_ leave containers and related untagged images around?

Comment: A recent commit moved the info provided my @BMW to https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/reference/commandline/images.md#untagged-images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `RUN` line in a Dockerfile is essentially equivalent to `docker run`ing the previous line's image. By default docker keeps all these intermediate images to help with caching, this speeds up subsequent builds. You can ask them to be removed when building by specifying the `--rm` or `--force-rm` flags.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This answer raised more questions to me now.